# How to solve Android JAR libs duplicate files error

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, eclipse-adt

I have two Android lib projects packaged as JAR files. When I put the two JARs in my project's libs folder the eclipse console throws me this error:

```
Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: res/values/attrs.xml
Origin 1: /Users/javier/dev/myProject/libs/facebook-sdk.jar
Origin 2: /Users/javier/dev/myProject/libs/sliding-menu.jar
```

There is a way to avoid this error without setting the projects as libraries of my application in Eclipse? I need to share my source code and I want that the project includes these libraries without sharing the facebook sdk project or sliding menu project folder.

Thanks

Comment: Your JAR file must not contain same files as in your main projec

Comment: @GDG I don't have any res/values/attrs.xml file in my project, the facebook sdk and the sliding menu projects have their own attrs.xml file, I cannot rename the file in one of the libraries because then I must fix the references to the file on that project, or this is the only way?